# Open pdf within rcp application as a separate view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My requirement is to open pdf files directly inside my RCP application as a separate view.
Currently the files are listed in a tree in the explorer view on clicking of which opens the  installed adobe reader.
I want to open it inhouse .
Please suggest.

Comment: Does it work via [_PDF.js_](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) in a browser widget?

Comment: Also Acrobat SDK provides  Inter Application Communication(IAC) support to render PDF files in external applications instead of opening Acrobat window. I will evaluate that first

Comment: PDF.js is what we are resorting to since Usage of the SDK from a Java based application using COM technology is not easy(need some additional C++ code as a wrapper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to load a PDF file within a SWT basic shell but it does not further allow to perform any other operation on it(zoom,select text, scroll etc..).
The PDF basically shows up as a image(of the first page) & is not further interactive.
Any suggestion how to get this done would be helpfull.
For the sample SWT application to load a PDF I followed this link(used the program ID of acrobat reader instead of word from the registry) :

https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet262.java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Had to finally discard the approach since COM based access from a Java application is not possible straight-away  & needs some additional wrapper logic in the form of C++ layer.